# What is the correct word order for words 跑步 and 轻快?

Tags: word-order

What is the correct word order for words 跑步 and 轻快?

> 跑步轻快
>
> 跑步的轻快 (seems like this version is extremely incorrect, also because of wrong character ***de*** usage)
>
> 轻快的跑步

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see no issue with 轻快的跑步 when you consider 跑步 (as a whole) a noun word.

If you take 跑步 as a verb, then 轻快地跑步 is ok.

For example,

> 轻快的跑步能让我们的身心得以放松。 // used as a noun.
>
> 我们在操场上轻快地跑步。 // used as a verb

In fact, I'd rather say 跑步 is used as a noun more often than a verb. For example, 跑步是一项很好的运动.

The single character 跑 is often used when serves as a verb, instead of 跑步. For example, 他跑得很快。We wouldn't say 他跑步得很快. This is because we take 跑步 as a noun usually.

So, 轻快的跑步 does make some sense in some circumstances.

跑步轻快 is a possible usage too, because 跑步轻快 could be considered to be the short version of 跑步跑得轻快.

However, 跑步的轻快 is not valid in any case, because 轻快 is adj or adv. You could say 跑步跑得轻快， but 跑步得轻快 is wrong because (as mentioned above) 跑步 is often used as a noun word.

Comment: Honestly best answer so far

Comment: Just hypothetically, how would you say "the ease of running"? Wouldn't that be 跑步的輕快? I know that 輕快 is an adjective / stative verb, but if it could be used as a noun, like 跑步的速度.

Comment: @Philipp, You play a little trick here. We translate "ease of cleaning" to 方便清洗， “ease of use” to 方便使用， so I would think "ease of running" is 方便跑步, or something that could make running easy like 使跑步变得容易/轻松/轻快. I would think "running with ease" is more like 轻快地跑步.

Comment: You're right, I wasn't being serious. I just wanted to point out that there are situations in which I can imagine "跑步的輕快". Imagine it as the title (or chapter heading) of a semi-esoteric book on "The art of running"

Comment: But it's probably more likely to find the expression without the "de" in between.

Comment: @Philipp, The thing is art 艺术 is noun, so 跑步的艺术 makes sense. 轻快 is not a noun in any case. Maybe you could take 轻快 as a kind of feeling. The only case I could think of is 它让我感受到了跑步的轻快感。 Maybe, it's ok you omit 感， like 它让我感受到了跑步的轻快. Still it's not a good sentence, better to say 它让我感受到了跑步中（/过程）的轻快感。

Answer (score 3):

I think the correct version is:

> 轻快**地**跑步 (Brisk walking / running)

where you might want to use **地 de**, as `轻快 qing1kuai4` here is modifying a verb `跑 pao3`.

Answer (score 1):

轻快地(not "的")跑步 is the correct order.

Use “地” here because “轻快” modifies the status of “跑步”(verb) as an adverb.

Answer (score 1):

“轻快地跑步” sounds the most natural.

“跑步得轻快” (notice that here the auxiliary is '得' for the adjective is placed after it) will sound rather strange, for '得' is usually followed by a one-character adjective, and preceded by a one-character verb. But it could be still changed to “他跑步跑得很轻快”, adding a '很' to cease the strangeness.

In both sayings, the elements placed in latter positions are emphasized: “轻快地跑步” emphasizes the action “跑步” (He is swiftly running rather than walking/jumping...) while “跑得很轻快” emphasizes the adjective “轻快” (He is a swift runner, not a slow one).

“跑步轻快” is also correct in another scenario, which is the parallel structure: “他跑步轻快，走路潇洒” (He runs swiftly and walks handsomely). Here “跑步” is more like a noun or the English gerund, and “轻快” is a predicate that modifies it.

Answer (score -1):

轻快的跑步
跑步很轻快

跑步轻快 is not a sentence.

Comment: Please distinguish among 的、地 and 得。

Comment: yes you are right轻快地跑步，you foreigners is better than me Chinese